# Why doesn't Eclipse recognize new JAR?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, jar

I've received a new SOAP service client JAR from a teammate, and am busy integrating it into my app.  I've put the JAR into the appropriate path, overwriting the previous version.  I've refreshed my workspace, performed a Clean and a Build, but...

...I'm not able to see any of the classes within the JAR through intellisense, even though code I utilize from the JAR will compile and execute correctly.  Furthermore, Eclipse is still trying to use the previous version of the JAR, in that when I perform a "fix imports", it re-imports the old classes, rather than the new ones.

The code builds and runs, but I have to reference classes absolutely, as opposed to relatively:

```
 org.acmewidgets.soap.inputs.HeaderType header = new org.acmewidgets.soap.inputs.HeaderType()
```

Instead of

```
 HeaderType header = new HeaderType()
```

The previous version of the JAR did not require this.

How do I "Force" Eclipse to ditch the old references and use the new ones?  Or, is Eclipse runnin' fine, and my new JAR is suspect?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you added it to the project classpath in Eclipse? Right click on the project and go to Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries. You may find that the old JAR is still listed there instead of the new JAR.

Comment: Also did you copy the JAR file using the Windows Explorer (or Mac Finder, or the command line etc)? Eclipse doesn't pick up changes to the file system automatically if you make those changes outside Eclipse. Try refreshing the project (Right click > Refresh).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like something got broken for good. If closing and opening the project again doesn't help, try this in order:

- If your project depends on other projects from the workspace, you could end up with *two* JARs in the classpath. Run tests or your app, then switch to the "Debug" perspective, select the project (which is terminated), then select "Properties" from the context menu. This gives you the classpath which was used.

  Copy that to the text editor and search for the JAR file and make sure you only have a single copy in the classpath.
- Search your workspace for the JAr file. Maybe there is a second copy which you don't expect.
- Create a new workspace (don't delete the old one, yet) and import the project. Does that help?
- Try the latest version of Eclipse (3.6.1)

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to refresh the project before going through these steps. OP may simply have copied the file using another program... Eclipse doesn't automatically detect changes that are made outside Eclipse.

Comment: Bingo!  Closing and reopening the project is the one thing I didn't try.  Strange that it worked, but closing and opening Eclipse, itself, did not.  Thanks!

Comment: @IVR, a caching problem.  Note that Eclipse actually HAS functionality for upgrading a jar - perhaps use that next time?

Comment: Check that you have the option "Automatically refresh workspace" turned on.

Comment: Really helped me in crisis, I was having other projects in my classpath referring multiple versions of the same jar. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add it as a '[User Library](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/buildpath/ref-preferences-user-libraries.htm)'.