# wsclient.jar created by wsimport could not be used

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsimport

I have wsdl file and can create client.jar typing following command.

```
wsimport -clientjar wsclient.jar mywsdl.wsdl.
```

But When I added this jar file into classpath folder of eclipse , eclipse does not detect classes inside the jar file. 
On the other hand, when I create just .class'es files and pointing this folder as a classpathfolder over eclipse, eclipse detectsit.

One more attempt I have .jar api file created somehow, when I have moved created artifact classess into this jar file, eclipse detects these classes as well.

These attempts shows me that jar file created by wsimport -clientjar does not work as I aspect, at least for this wsdl file. Actuall I do not think that wsimport does not work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Eclipse is just screwing with you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628345/why-doesnt-eclipse-recognize-new-jar?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the `-clientjar` options does not do what you expect.

The purpose of the `-clientjar` option is to embed WSDL metadata in your build so that it can become part of the consumer application's jar file. This way the web service consumer does not have to download the WSDL every time it is initialized but can instead use an WSDL which is bundled with the application itself.

There are [several things happening](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24512809/1504556) when you use the `-clientjar` option. Yes, you'll get a file called `wsclient.jar` as in your example but the most important thing is that it generates `META-INF/wsdl/<servicename>.wsdl` file and this file gets referenced in the generated Java code, ready to be used.

I suggest to have a look at the generated Java code with and without the `-clientjar` option then you can see what I mean.

See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24512809/1504556) for more information.